# Normal C-c in ansi-term

Tags: key-bindings, ansi-term, prefix-keys

In `ansi-term`, it automatically rebinds `C-c` to have the same keybindings as `C-x`. I want to turn this behaviour off, so I can access the keybindings I have behind `C-c`. (I know about `C-c C-j`, but that's too many keys for my taste.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute the key you prefer for `C-c` in the following call to `term-set-escape-char` in order to change the value of `term-escape-char` to some other key, and then unbind `C-c` from the `term-char-mode` keymap.

```el
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(progn (term-set-escape-char ?\C-c)
          (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c") nil)))
```

To send a literal `C-c` to the terminal, you would use your chosen key followed by `C-c`.

Similarly for the other `term-char-mode` bindings mentioned at
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Term Mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Remember that this only affects char mode, so switching from line mode to char mode would still be `C-c C-k` even if switching from char mode to line mode was no longer `C-c C-j`. You can change line mode bindings in `term-mode-map` if need be.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant. By default in ansi-term, Emacs rebinds C-c to C-x (more or less). So I can't access keybindings like e.g. C-c r, because it'll try to run C-x r instead.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand, but I didn't include unbinding `C-c` after calling `term-set-escape-char`. I've added that.